# How to use res.send method after clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, send

I have to make continuous output to the server console of the current date and time.
I have to stop output to the console after the specified time and return the current date and time to the user. How should I use ClearInterval() correctly?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

let timerId = setInterval(() => console.log(new Date().toUTCString()), 1000);

const r = app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let lastDate = clearInterval(timerId);
    res.send(lastDate);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: is specified time coming in request?

Comment: Sounds like you want to `res.send(new Date().toUTCString());`, or make a variable to store the last calculated date and return that.  The return value of any clearInterval call is undefined.

Comment: @mss Current time

Comment: @James Thanks exatcly what i want. 
Also do you know how to make "19.01.2021, 15:49:24" instead of  "Tue, 19 Jan 2021 15:49:24 GMT", i mean instead of toUTCString()? And also current time in my country is +2 hours (GMT +2) (I can edit question also for that if it has to)
P.S (if you don't mind upwote this question, because i can't ask anymore because of low reputation)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `res.send(new Date().toUTCString())`

And to add `+2` hours to your current time you can do

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours( date.getHours() + 2 );
var newDate = date;
res.send(newDate)
```